# Entity Framework Core how do I store information by username?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm working through the pluralsight course "Building a Web App with Dot Net Core"
And I've run into a problem trying to store information that is tied to a username with EF Core. I am able to login to my website and restrict access to pages by username, but right now I'm trying to use Postman with chrome interceptor to perform an HTTP GET that will show that I am receiving info specific to the user. When I perform this GET(on localhost:54999/api/trips/) all I'm receiving is a blank array [ ]

I've looked through all the files that I thought were relevant and compared them with the solution code that pluralsight provided and still haven't found the problem. Here are some relevant pieces of my code. I don't need anyone to solve this for me, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

TripsController.cs

```
        [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            //if (true) return BadRequest("Bad things happend");
            try
            {
                var results = _repository.GetTripsByUsername(this.User.Identity.Name);
                return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TripViewModel>>(results));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO Logging 
                _logger.LogError($"Failed to get All Trips: {ex}");
                return BadRequest("Error occurred");
            }



        }
```

World Repository.cs

```
public object GetTripsByUsername(string name)
{
    return _context.Trips
      .Where(t => t.UserName == name)
      .ToList();
}
```

WorldContext.cs

```
namespace TheWorld.Models
{
    public class WorldContext : IdentityDbContext<WorldUser>
    {
        private IConfigurationRoot _config;
        public WorldContext(IConfigurationRoot config, DbContextOptions options) 
            : base(options)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Stop> Stops { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:BigProjectContextConnection"]);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, WorldContextSeedData.cs

```
namespace TheWorld.Models
{
    public class WorldContextSeedData
    {
        private WorldContext _context;
        private UserManager<WorldUser> _userManager;

        public WorldContextSeedData(WorldContext context, UserManager<WorldUser> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task EnsureSeedData()
        {
            if (await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("tonymartinez@theworld.com") == null)
            {
                var user = new WorldUser()
                {
                    UserName = "tonymartinez",
                    Email = "tonymartinez@theworld.com"
                };

                await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@ssw0rd!");
            }

            if (!_context.Trips.Any())
            {
                var usTrip = new Trip()
                {
                    DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Name = "US Trip",
                    UserName = "tonymartinez",
                    Stops = new List<Stop>()
          {
            new Stop() {  Name = "Atlanta, GA", Arrival = new DateTime(2014, 6, 4), Latitude = 33.748995, Longitude = -84.387982, Order = 0 },
            new Stop() {  Name = "New York, NY", Arrival = new DateTime(2014, 6, 9), Latitude = 40.712784, Longitude = -74.005941, Order = 1 },
            new Stop() {  Name = "Boston, MA", Arrival = new DateTime(2014, 7, 1), Latitude = 42.360082, Longitude = -71.058880, Order = 2 },
            new Stop() {  Name = "Chicago, IL", Arrival = new DateTime(2014, 7, 10), Latitude = 41.878114, Longitude = -87.629798, Order = 3 },
            new Stop() {  Name = "Seattle, WA", Arrival = new DateTime(2014, 8, 13), Latitude = 47.606209, Longitude = -122.332071, Order = 4 },
            new Stop() {  Name = "Atlanta, GA", Arrival = new DateTime(2014, 8, 23), Latitude = 33.748995, Longitude = -84.387982, Order = 5 },
          }
                };

                _context.Trips.Add(usTrip);

                _context.Stops.AddRange(usTrip.Stops);

                var worldTrip = new Trip()
                {
                    DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Name = "WorldTrip",
                    UserName = "tonymartinez",
                    Stops = new List<Stop>()
          {
            new Stop() { Order = 0, Latitude =  33.748995, Longitude =  -84.387982, Name = "Atlanta, Georgia", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jun 3, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 1, Latitude =  48.856614, Longitude =  2.352222, Name = "Paris, France", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jun 4, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 2, Latitude =  50.850000, Longitude =  4.350000, Name = "Brussels, Belgium", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jun 25, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 3, Latitude =  51.209348, Longitude =  3.224700, Name = "Bruges, Belgium", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jun 28, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 4, Latitude =  48.856614, Longitude =  2.352222, Name = "Paris, France", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jun 30, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 5, Latitude =  51.508515, Longitude =  -0.125487, Name = "London, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jul 8, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 6, Latitude =  51.454513, Longitude =  -2.587910, Name = "Bristol, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jul 24, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 7, Latitude =  52.078000, Longitude =  -2.783000, Name = "Stretton Sugwas, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jul 29, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 8, Latitude =  51.864211, Longitude =  -2.238034, Name = "Gloucestershire, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jul 30, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 9, Latitude =  52.954783, Longitude =  -1.158109, Name = "Nottingham, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jul 31, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 10, Latitude =  51.508515, Longitude =  -0.125487, Name = "London, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 1, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 11, Latitude =  55.953252, Longitude =  -3.188267, Name = "Edinburgh, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 5, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 12, Latitude =  55.864237, Longitude =  -4.251806, Name = "Glasgow, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 6, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 13, Latitude =  57.149717, Longitude =  -2.094278, Name = "Aberdeen, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 7, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 14, Latitude =  55.953252, Longitude =  -3.188267, Name = "Edinburgh, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 8, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 15, Latitude =  51.508515, Longitude =  -0.125487, Name = "London, UK", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 10, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 16, Latitude =  52.370216, Longitude =  4.895168, Name = "Amsterdam, Netherlands", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 14, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 17, Latitude =  48.583148, Longitude =  7.747882, Name = "Strasbourg, France", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 17, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 18, Latitude =  46.519962, Longitude =  6.633597, Name = "Lausanne, Switzerland", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 19, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 19, Latitude =  46.021073, Longitude =  7.747937, Name = "Zermatt, Switzerland", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 27, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 20, Latitude =  46.519962, Longitude =  6.633597, Name = "Lausanne, Switzerland", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Aug 29, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 21, Latitude =  53.349805, Longitude =  -6.260310, Name = "Dublin, Ireland", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Sep 2, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 22, Latitude =  54.597285, Longitude =  -5.930120, Name = "Belfast, Northern Ireland", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Sep 7, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 23, Latitude =  53.349805, Longitude =  -6.260310, Name = "Dublin, Ireland", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Sep 9, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 24, Latitude =  47.368650, Longitude =  8.539183, Name = "Zurich, Switzerland", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Sep 16, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 25, Latitude =  48.135125, Longitude =  11.581981, Name = "Munich, Germany", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Sep 19, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 26, Latitude =  50.075538, Longitude =  14.437800, Name = "Prague, Czech Republic", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Sep 21, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 27, Latitude =  51.050409, Longitude =  13.737262, Name = "Dresden, Germany", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Oct 1, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 28, Latitude =  50.075538, Longitude =  14.437800, Name = "Prague, Czech Republic", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Oct 4, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 29, Latitude =  42.650661, Longitude =  18.094424, Name = "Dubrovnik, Croatia", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Oct 10, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 30, Latitude =  42.697708, Longitude =  23.321868, Name = "Sofia, Bulgaria", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Oct 16, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 31, Latitude =  45.658928, Longitude =  25.539608, Name = "Brosov, Romania", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Oct 20, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 32, Latitude =  41.005270, Longitude =  28.976960, Name = "Istanbul, Turkey", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Nov 1, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 33, Latitude =  45.815011, Longitude =  15.981919, Name = "Zagreb, Croatia", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Nov 11, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 34, Latitude =  41.005270, Longitude =  28.976960, Name = "Istanbul, Turkey", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Nov 15, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 35, Latitude =  50.850000, Longitude =  4.350000, Name = "Brussels, Belgium", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Nov 25, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 36, Latitude =  50.937531, Longitude =  6.960279, Name = "Cologne, Germany", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Nov 30, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 37, Latitude =  48.208174, Longitude =  16.373819, Name = "Vienna, Austria", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Dec 4, 2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 38, Latitude =  47.497912, Longitude =  19.040235, Name = "Budapest, Hungary", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Dec 28,2014") },
            new Stop() { Order = 39, Latitude =  37.983716, Longitude =  23.729310, Name = "Athens, Greece", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jan 2, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 40, Latitude =  -25.746111, Longitude =  28.188056, Name = "Pretoria, South Africa", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jan 19, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 41, Latitude =  43.771033, Longitude =  11.248001, Name = "Florence, Italy", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Feb 1, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 42, Latitude =  45.440847, Longitude =  12.315515, Name = "Venice, Italy", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Feb 9, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 43, Latitude =  43.771033, Longitude =  11.248001, Name = "Florence, Italy", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Feb 13, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 44, Latitude =  41.872389, Longitude =  12.480180, Name = "Rome, Italy", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Feb 17, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 45, Latitude =  28.632244, Longitude =  77.220724, Name = "New Delhi, India", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Mar 4, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 46, Latitude =  27.700000, Longitude =  85.333333, Name = "Kathmandu, Nepal", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Mar 10, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 47, Latitude =  28.632244, Longitude =  77.220724, Name = "New Delhi, India", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Mar 11, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 48, Latitude =  22.1667, Longitude =  113.5500, Name = "Macau", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Mar 21, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 49, Latitude =  22.396428, Longitude =  114.109497, Name = "Hong Kong", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Mar 24, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 50, Latitude =  39.904030, Longitude =  116.407526, Name = "Beijing, China", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Apr 19, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 51, Latitude =  22.396428, Longitude =  114.109497, Name = "Hong Kong", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Apr 24, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 52, Latitude =  1.352083, Longitude =  103.819836, Name = "Singapore", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Apr 30, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 53, Latitude =  3.139003, Longitude =  101.686855, Name = "Kuala Lumpor, Malaysia", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("May 7, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 54, Latitude =  13.727896, Longitude =  100.524123, Name = "Bangkok, Thailand", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("May 24, 2015") },
            new Stop() { Order = 55, Latitude =  33.748995, Longitude =  -84.387982, Name = "Atlanta, Georgia", Arrival = DateTime.Parse("Jun 17, 2015") },
          }
                };

                _context.Trips.Add(worldTrip);

                _context.Stops.AddRange(worldTrip.Stops);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two potential issues with the code above.

1. You are returning a type `object` from your `GetTripsByUsername(string name)` repository. I would have expected to see `public List<Trip> GetTripsByUsername(string name)`.
2. It looks like you have not defined what the `Mapper` is actually meant to map in your `Controller` method. I presume you are using `AutoMapper`, if so, you need to define your mappings. This is generally gone on `Application_Start`. Have a look at the AutoMapper [getting started guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started).